# Unresolved symbol when building AWS CPP SDK

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I am trying to build AWS CPP SDK on Linux but the build fails with the following error (resolved symbol_:
Can anyone shed some light on this error? ( I use devtoolset-6 gcc 6.3.1 for STL library support and clang 3.8.)

=================================

```
[ RUN      ] DefaultRateLimitTest.fractionalLimitTest
[       OK ] DefaultRateLimitTest.fractionalLimitTest (0 ms)
[----------] 11 tests from DefaultRateLimitTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 226 tests from 33 test cases ran. (4137 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 226 tests.
[100%] Built target aws-cpp-sdk-core-tests
[100%] Building CXX object aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests/CMakeFiles/aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests.dir/RunTests.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests/CMakeFiles/aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests.dir/TextToSpeechManagerTests.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests
/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/bin/ld: ../aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech/libaws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech.a(PulseAudioPCMOutputDriver.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pa_strerror@@PULSE_0'
//lib64/libpulse.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests/aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests] Error 1
make[1]: *** [aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests/CMakeFiles/aws-cpp-sdk-text-to-speech-tests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We recently pushed an update for this. It was missing -lpulse.

A fresh pull should fix the problem.